# Android RecyclerView Saving State Information

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView whose adapter holds a SortedList of objects I can not modify.

My cards inside the RecyclerView should expand/collapse on click showing additional information when expanded. The problem is that there seems to be no way to store the information whether a card is expanded or collapsed since the ViewHolder gets recycled.

To make things more difficult, new items are added at the beginning and at the end of my adapter, so the positions change all the time. Even though new cards should be shown collapsed, they are sometimes shown as expanded when a ViewHolder of an expanded card gets recycled for the new card. This is when I tried to save the expand/collapse information in the ViewHolder directly.

Comment: Could you simply create an array parallel to your list of objects, that stores whether each item is expanded or collapsed? You would have to keep some effort to keep it synchronized with the list. (And what do you mean by SortedList... ArrayList? SortedSet?)

Comment: You could also store dummy objects in the list, with two properties: the original (unmodifiable) object, and a boolean indicating whether the item is expanded or collapsed.

Comment: @gengkev I'm using the [SortedList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/SortedList.html) implementation from the support library. I tried the dummy object approach already, but due to recycling this also did not work as intended.

Comment: What I meant was to store the dummy object in the SortedList, which shouldn't be recycled, not in the ViewHolder. Does that work?

Comment: The problem there was that I don't have access to the dummy object in the ViewHolder. I also tried hooking into onCreateViewHolder() and use getItemViewType() to access the dummy object, so I could pass the expand/collapsed information to the view holder, but it seems like even getItemViewType() is not always called when adding items to the RecyclerView.

Comment: The way I've done it in the past, the ViewHolder class has no code; it's all in the Adapter. The list would be part of the adapter, and the `onBindViewHolder` method of the adapter would be able to retrieve items from the list and update the ViewHolder with the correct item. How did you do it?

Comment: The way I understand it, the ViewHolder class is only a temporary holder for your data, and it should not be tied to information about any specific object in the list. This is because it will be used to display many different objects by recycling. The ViewHolder should be updated to reflect an object's contents in the `onBindViewHolder` method.

Comment: OK, I got it. The correct solution is to use a dummy object and set the saved view state from that object in the onBindViewHolder() method.

The problem in my case was that the API that returns my objects sometimes returned the same objects that then overwrote the state in the dummy object. I hacked a state transfer into the areContentsTheSame() method of the SortedList's callback. With that it works! :)

Comment: That does sound a bit painful, but glad to hear that you figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution seems to be using a wrapper object with two properties: the original (unmodifiable) object, and a boolean indicating whether the item is expanded or collapsed.

Then in the onBindViewHolder() method of the RecyclerView's adapter, you have to set your views to expanded or collapsed depending on the state of the wrapper object.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder ui, int position) {
    if(wrapper_objects.get(position).expanded) {
        expandView(ui);
    } else {
        collapseView(ui);
    }

    // expand/collapse on click
    ui.expand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(wrapper_objects.get(position).expanded) {
                collapseView(ui);
                wrapper_objects.get(position).expanded = false;
            } else {
                expandView(ui);
                wrapper_objects.get(position).expanded = true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

An additional problem, but rare problem might be that an API sometimes returns the same objects that were already in the SortedList. In this case, they then overwrite the expand/collapse state in the wrapper object. A hackish solution I found for this is doing this:

```
private SortedList<WrapperObject> wrapper_objects = new SortedList<>(WrapperObject.class, new SortedList.Callback<WrapperObject>(){
    @Override
     public boolean areContentsTheSame(WrapperObject old, WrapperObject new) {
        // keep state in new wrapper object
        new.expanded = old.expanded;

        return old.object.equals(new.object);
    }
}
```